# Nested scheduling support in Quartz

Tags: scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler, job-scheduling, quartz

I have a business requirement that requires the following scheduling pattern

----t1--------ta-------tb---------t2

Between **t1 and t2**, give 10% discount on product A
However, for nested time window **ta - tb**, give discount of 20%.
When **tb** is reached, go back to 10% discount on product A until t2.

Can Quartz job scheduling implement this out of the box?
I want to avoid scheduling 3 jobs here - for intervals **(t1, ta) (ta, tb) and (tb, t2).**

Comment: ahuman, could you please check my answer and accept it if addresses your requirements, or provide further details in case it does not. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Quartz is a generic Java scheduling API and as such it does not come with any application-specific business logic "out of the box". The way I would solve the above requirement with Quartz is like so:

1. Create a generic ProductPriceUpdaterJob Quartz job that will simply update the product price stored in your product store (typically a database). The job would expect a single job data map parameter "discount" with the discount percentage figure (i.e. 0, 10, 20).
2. Associate the job with 4 Quartz triggers (T1, Ta, Tb, T2) that start your job at t1, ta, tb and t2 respectively. These triggers would specify the desired discount amount in their job data map (T1 has discount=10, Ta has discount=20, Tb has discount=10, T2 has discount=0).
3. Start Quartz and register the job and triggers with it and you are done.

At t1, Quartz starts your job using trigger T1 and the job applies the 10% discount to the product price. At ta, Quartz starts your job using trigger Ta and your job applies the 20% discount to the product price etc.

Quartz supports 4 different trigger types and I think you can safely use the CronTrigger type for your triggers.

You will probably want to use another job data map parameter in your triggers where you can specify the ID (or IDs) of the product(s) to apply the discount to. This way, your job will be truly generic and usable with all your products.